# how can i make height and width auto resize according the screen?

Tags: html, text, scroll, autoresize

This is the code i am using to add a scrolling text in a mobile app project.

```
<style type="text/css">
     .scroll {      
         padding: 10px;      
         height: 280px;
         width: 580px; 
         overflow: scroll;
     }
</style>

<div class="scroll"> 
    <p>put paragraph here</p> 
</div>    `enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below :

```
<style type="text/css">
     .scroll {      
         padding: 10px;      

         width: 100%; 
         overflow:auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     }
</style>
```

Check Out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6G2r/)

Comment: YOu are test in mobile??

Comment: Try adding  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: this doesn't help me my friend , i am not that advanced.

Comment: If you want simple scroll then use css written in my answer